# Still hearing sound of old view after new view is loaded

Tags: ios, uiview, avplayer

I'm running into an issue: I'm successfully transitioning from one view to the next one - from view containing a static image to one containing a video (mov or mp4, etc using avPlayer), vice versa or whatever else type of sequence.

However when I'm transitioning from a view containing a video to a one containing an image I'm still hearing the sound of the video after the image is loaded. Strange. The funniest is that it does not happen when I transitioning from video to video... Any idea guys?

Please check the code I'm using to transition the view (with a dissolve effect):

```
- (void) replaceView: (UIView *) theCurrentView withView: (UIView *) theReplacementView
{

    theReplacementView.alpha = 0.0;
    [self.view addSubview: theReplacementView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.5
                     animations:^{
                         theCurrentView.alpha = 0.0;
                         theReplacementView.alpha = 1.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [theCurrentView removeFromSuperview];
                     }];


    self.currentView = theReplacementView;
    [self.view addSubview:theReplacementView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly stop video playback in viewWillDisappear method.

Comment: Does not work in viewWillDisappear but it actually does if I put a line right after "theReplacementView.alpha = 1.0;" like this:

theReplacementView.alpha = 1.0;
[avPlayer pause];